# How to enable download function in django if XLSX file in django folder?

Tags: python, django, excel, pandas

I have multiple dataframe which I want to store in the excelsheet, hence I write the following code:**view.py**

```
NEWExcel=pd.ExcelWriter('K(1).xlsx')
NEWT.to_excel(NEWExcel,'Step1_result', index=False)
NEWTM.to_excel(NEWExcel,'Step1_Result_by_month', index=False)
NEWExcel.save()
```

and it successfully store in my folder and I can open and view the data, but after I create a button in order for me to download the excelsheet:**index.html**

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Archive</button>
<script>function myFunction(){download('K(1).xlsx');}</script>
```

after I click the button, the file able to download but fail to read the data inside, the following box was shown when I open the file that I download:

Anyone have any ideas to help me solve this? because I new to this and hope that can get idea from here. Thanks

Comment: "Following box was shown". What box?

Comment: Excel cannot open ....because the file format or extension is not valid

Comment: show us the view where you send the file to the client

Comment: In my view.py, i have 2 dataframe that created by pandas. NEWT is my first dataframe while NEWTM is my second dataframe. Then I create a blank excel sheet which is K(1).xlsx and the 2 dataframe will be store in this excel sheet. After that it will save to the file which together with the script. After that in my UI i will create the button with about code and when user click on it the file will be downloaded. User able to download but when open up the excel is corrupted. but when i manually open from the file that the excel was store it can be open and no corrupt